# $_.ReceivedTime Outlook formatting in Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

I have a simple set using the get-outlookinbox cmd created by the script guys

I have it set up to pull my sent mailbox, match the subject title, count how many emails have been sent and by who which match. My issue is that I also have it set up to check after a date however I want to set it up so that it'll search between a range.

```
$inbox | Where-Object { $_.subject -match 'x'} | where-object { $_.ReceivedTime -gt "06 11 2018" } | Group-Object -Property senderName -NoElement | Sort-Object count
```

how would you edit this part to give you a range check?

```
where-object { $_.ReceivedTime -gt "06 11 2018" }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give two dates to search between:

```
Where-Object { ($_.ReceivedTime -gt "06 11 2018") -and ($_.ReceivedTime -lt "06 15 2018") }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use filters like that - they are horrible from the performance point of view as each item needs to be instantiated, initialized, and returned by the Outlook Object Model.
Let the underlying store provider do the work - use [Items.Find/FindNext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/items-findnext-method-outlook) or [Items.Restrict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/items-restrict-method-outlook).

Answer (score 0):

Just a remark - as it might be not obvious which script you're talking about, would be good to link it in your question in the future. I assume you're talking about [this one](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/af63364d-8b04-473f-9a98-b5ab37e6b024).

To get emails from specified date range you have to use `-lt` operator (lower than) in conjunction with `-gt`:

```
where { $_.ReceivedTime -gt [datetime]"5/5/11" -AND $_.ReceivedTime -lt [datetime]"5/10/11" }
```

This example has been taken from help of this cmdlet, feel free to check for more examples using:

```
Get-Help Get-OutlookInBox -Examples
```